# Android Ksoap2 web service for download/Upload

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I want to write a program using `ksoap` web service and download a file to android mobile from web service. I must access a text file from web service and download it in the android mobile.Can some one help me with tutorial or links corresponding it

Comment: I have no idea but i wrote a program to access values from web service and did that. but i dont have idea of downloading or uploading a file.

Answer (score 7):

`KSOAP` is simply send request and getting responds. Lot of example are there in web search and get your suitable example. Here some examples
[Example 1](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-development-tutorial)

[Example 2](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/167-using-ksoap2-for-android-soap-web-service)

[Example 3](http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2012/04/accessing-webservices-using-soap.html)

[Example 4](http://androidtestexample.blogspot.in/2012/02/soap.html)

For uploading and downloading the files through the SOAP web service I'm using the following method

### Uploading:

1. Convert your text file to Binary String
2. Store it into the single string
3. send it through the soap web service

Example

```
Uri uriString = Uri.parse(objBundle.get("").toString());
File file = new File(uriString.getPath());
FileInputStream objFileIS;
objFileIS = new FileInputStream(file);
ByteArrayOutputStream objByteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] byteBufferString = new byte[1024];
for (int readNum; (readNum = objFileIS.read(byteBufferString)) != -1;) 
{
objByteArrayOS.write(byteBufferString, 0, readNum);
system.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
}                    
byte[] byteBinaryData = Base64.encode((objByteArrayOS.toByteArray()), Base64.DEFAULT);
strAttachmentCoded = new String(byteBinaryData);
```

### Download:

1. Ask the server side developers to send the your file in the format of binary string
2. Get the responds string and convert it as a file and store it in sdcard.

Example

```
byte[] bytes;
strBinaryPDFString = cursorGetBinaryString.getString(0);//Index position of the binary string in table
File createfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/Folder/");
createfile.mkdirs();
File outputFile = new File(createfile,"FileName.pdf");//creating temporary file in phone Memory
new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
bytes = Base64.decode(strBinaryPDFString,Base64.DEFAULT);
File filepath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/Folder/FileName.pdf");
OutputStream pdffos = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
pdffos.write(bytes);//writing the binary string into the payslip.pdf temporary file
pdffos.flush();
pdffos.close();
```

The above method is working fine for me. May be you can find another best method.

Comment: Android Apple iam aware of web service but i want a exmple for upload/downloading a text file

Comment: Links down. Please re update them if available any where.