# SoapObject Add property xml string in Webservice using ksoap2

Tags: android, xml, web-services, xml-serialization, ksoap2

I created XML string using XmlSerializer and it prints out as

```
<tag> string </tag>
```

I want to add the xml string to SOAPObject and get response from web service.
So I added and when I print out the requestDump the < and > are being replaced by &lt ; and  &gt ;

I assume that it is being encoded by HttpTransportSE.

I read here [Android Ksoap2 web service for download/Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486543/android-ksoap2-web-service-for-download-upload) and it says I need to convert my string to binary before uploading? I am confused because the API tells us to upload xml. Currently, there is no error or exception but the result is empty. I think it's the encoding problem.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Probably I'm late for you but this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164419/passing-xmldataset-as-parameter-ksoap2-android

Answer (score 0):

When using ksoap2 you don't have to handle the serialization yourself. If you want to add an entry to the xml like this:

```
<tag>string</tag>
```

Then you just have to call this when constructing the `SoapObject` you are sending to the server:

```
soapObject.addProperty("tag", "string");
```

Also modifying the requestDump is never a good idea. This output is just for debug purposes. That's the reason why you have to set `transport.debug = true;` for the requestDump or responseDump to even appear. As I said above just use the `addProperty()` and `addSoapObject()` methods to construct your request.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it doesn't really help me. I understand what you mean. I need xml in that "string". Transport debug is set to true. I did use 'addProperty()' and 'addSoapObject()' too but the result is empty.

Comment: Oh now I understand what you mean. You want to send the xml `<tag>string</tag>`, but you are worried because in the request dump the < and > etc are encoded? That is completely normal, you don't have to worry about that. Since the `SoapEnvelope` is XML you cannot send a String containing < or > or any other important character, to get around this problem all < and > etc in the payload are replaced with encoded characters like `&lt;` and `&gt;`. When the request reaches your server those encoded characters will be converted back to < or >.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SoapObject.setInnerText("...");` to add CDATA text to a Ksoap2 request.