# Passing XML(DataSet) as Parameter ksoap2 android

Tags: android, xml, web-services, wsdl, android-ksoap2

i am trying to send XML requst to webservice using ksop2 
but it is not workig

my web service request format is

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <UpdateVehicleViaObj xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <userHash>[string?]</userHash>
            <vehicleObject>
                <Colour xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/StockService">[string?]</Colour>
                <Comments xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/StockService">[string?]</Comments>
                <Condition xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/StockService">[string?]</Condition>                
            </vehicleObject>
        </UpdateVehicleViaObj>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

i am  using ksoap2 to create request like

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject("Namespace", "methodname");
  request.addProperty(properyObject);

 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        //SOAP is implemented in dotNet true/false.
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        MarshalDouble md = new MarshalDouble();
        //envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        md.register(envelope);
        //Set request data into envelope and send request using HttpTransport
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(mInObj.getUrl(), networkTimeOut);

        androidHttpTransport.debug= true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SoapAction, envelope,headerPropertyArrayList);
```

and ksop2 make requst become like this

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header /><v:Body><UpdateVehicleViaObj xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" id="o0" c:root="1"><userHash>B5B2FDF87E848946</userHash><vehicleObject>&lt;Colour&gt;red&lt;/Colour&gt;&lt;
&lt;Comments &gt;red&lt;/Comments &gt;&lt;&lt;Condition &gt;red&lt;/Condition &gt;&lt;</vehicleObject></UpdateVehicleViaObj></v:Body></v:Envelope>
```

please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the documentation of ksoap2

https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#sending/receiving_array_of_complex_types_or_primitives

you can create class that will implement marshable interface and add other property inside that class

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late, but I just solved it implementing KvmSerializable class, and inside that class, the CDATA String was declared as a SoapObject. Then, I set the CDATA with SoapObject.setInnerText

```
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);


        SoapObject fieldWithCdata = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "fieldWithCData");
        fieldWithCdata.setInnerText(cDatraString);

        CustomClass customClass = new customClass(string1, string2, string3, fieldWithCdata);


        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
        pi.setName("customClass");
        pi.setValue(customClass);

        request.addProperty(pi);
```

and in the CustomClass

```
public class CustomClass implements KvmSerializable{


private String string1;
private String string2;
private String string3;
private SoapObject fieldWithCdata;
```

`...`

```
 public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    switch (index)
    {
        case INDEX_STRING1: //0
            this.string1 = value.toString();
            break;
        case INDEX_STRING2: //1
            this.string2 = value.toString();
            break;
        case INDEX_STRING3: //2
            this.string3 = value.toString();
            break;
        case INDEX_FIELDWITHCDATA://3
            this.fieldWithCdata = (SoapObject) value;
            break;
    }
```

with

```
  public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable properties, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch(index){
        case INDEX_STRING1:
            info.name = "string1";
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            break;
        case INDEX_STRING2:
            info.name = "string2";
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            break;
        case INDEX_STRING3:
            info.name = "string3";
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            break;
        case INDEX_FIELDWITHCDATA:
            info.name = "fieldWithCdata";
            info.type = PropertyInfo.OBJECT_TYPE;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```